# Confusion about Unittesting with Vitest, while only having +page.svelte files

Tags: testing, svelte, sveltekit, vitest

For my university work I need to learn Testing using Vitest in a Svelte Project. So far I understand the basics and was able to write basic tests. Now I need to test the code written by my colleagues in Svelte. The Problem is that I don't really know what exactly to import, if all I have are +page.svelte files. What do I need to import to test a specific function?

For example using:

```
import footer from "../src/routes/+layout.svelte";

describe("Layout Test", () => {
    test("that footer is being rendered", () => {
        const host = document.createElement('div');

        document.body.appendChild(host);

        const instance = new footer({target: host});

        expect(instance).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

I get a passed test. Did this actually test if the footer exists or am I misunderstanding something? Did it even test the footer from the +layout.svelte page?

Any help is greatly appreciated <3

Tried researching the problem, expected it to solve my question, but no source i found helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test components, you can use [Svelte Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/intro) in combination with vitest.

You can find examples in the "Example" section but basically, you should render components using the "render" function and you get specific elements by test-id or text, etc... (Check the coreApi -> queries).

In your case, I would do:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import footer from "../src/routes/+layout.svelte";

describe("Layout Test", () => {
    it("renders the footer", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(footer);
        expect(getByTestId('footer')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Note: remember to add a "data-testid" to your footer if you wish to use the "getByTestId" query.